# Auto upload using github or sourcetree

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, atlassian-sourcetree

I have some simple php projects which are only using PHP(Connect to Mysql) + HTML + CSS.
I use sourcetree to upload them to the github and using ftp client to upload them to the EC2 or Manually zip them and upload to the elastic beanstalk .
I wonder that can I use some tools or script can let me upload the file automatically when i click the sourcetree's push button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, on the commit sheet you can click on a checkbox towards the bottom of the sheet that says "Push commit immediately to.."

[image: Source Image]

I would try to comment but I do not have enough reputation to do so.
Let me know if this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use define [Sourcetree Custom Action](https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/02/08/custom-actions-more-power-to-you/) where:

- you would do the `git push` (see "[Using Git in Custom Actions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-git-in-custom-actions-785323500.html)")
- call a separate script which does the packaging/upload to EC2 for you.